# what can be put into node tag args=" HERE"

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the args attribute in  tag can have many values and I am wondering what kinds of values we should assign to args attributes in  tag. For example, the following launch file:

```
<launch>

    <arg name="base" default="$(env BULLETSIM_SOURCE_DIR)/data/bagfiles"/>
    <arg name="filename" />
    <arg name="camera" default="kinect1"/>

    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
        <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera)" />
        <arg name="load_driver" value="false" />
        <arg name="depth_registration" value="true" />
    </include>

    <node name="rosbag_$(arg camera)" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="-k --clock $(arg base)/$(arg filename).bag" /> 

    <!--
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-l $(arg base)/$(arg filename).bag /kinect1:=/kinect1_rec" /> 
    <node pkg="image_transport" type="republish" name="image_transport_color" args="theora in:=/kinect1_rec/rgb/image_rect_color raw out:=/kinect1/rgb/image_rect_color" />
    -->

</launch>
```

Another launch file is like this:

```
<launch>

    <arg name="camera" default="kinect1"/>
    <arg name="online" default="true"/>
    <arg name="bus" default="1"/>
    <arg name="filename"/>

    <group if="$(arg online)">
        <param name="use_sim_time" value="false" />
        <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
            <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera)" />
            <arg name="device_id" value="$(arg bus)@0" />
            <arg name="depth_registration" value="true" />
        </include>
    </group>
    <group unless="$(arg online)">
        <param name="use_sim_time" value="true" />
        <include file="play_cloud.launch">
            <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera)" />
            <arg name="filename" value="$(arg filename)" />
        </include>
    </group>

    <node name="drop1" pkg="topic_tools" type="drop" args="/$(arg camera)/depth_registered/points 2 3 /drop/points"/>
    <node name="preprocessor" pkg="binary_symlinks" type="qpreprocessor_node" output="screen"  args="--inputTopic=/drop/points --downsample=0.008 --removeOutliers=true --outlierRadius=0.016 --outlierMinK=0 --clusterMinSize=15 --zClipLow=-0.02 --backgroundRead=false --backgroundFile=/home/alex/Desktop/preprocessor.yml" /> 

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219561/what-can-be-put-into-node-tag--args=%22-here%22/) by [johnny.lin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22452/johnny.lin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `args` argument contains arguments that are directly passed unaltered to the executable when starting it. Your second example for instance is the same as manually starting the node using rosrun like this (ignoring the node name change):

```
rosrun binary_symlinks qpreprocessor_node --inputTopic=/drop/points --downsample=0.008 --removeOutliers=true --outlierRadius=0.016 --outlierMinK=0 --clusterMinSize=15 --zClipLow=-0.02 --backgroundRead=false --backgroundFile=/home/alex/Desktop/preprocessor.yml
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1